# How to use stat() to check if commandline argument is a directory?

Tags: c, unix, posix, stat

Im trying to count the types of files inputted into a program. So if you enter echo.c its a C source, echo.h is Header and so on. But if you input a directory, like `echo/root` it should count as an `directory` type but right now its counting as a `exe` type. Ive gotten everything else working, im just trying to figure out how to use `stat()` to check if the `argv` is a directory.

Heres what I have so far:

```
#include <sys/stat.h> 

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
int cCount = 0;
int cHeadCount = 0;
int dirCount = 0; 


for(int i = 1; i < argc; i++){

    FILE *fi = fopen(argv[i], "r");

    if(!fi){
        fprintf(stderr,"File not found: %s", argv[i]);
    }
    else{

    struct stat directory;
    //if .c extension > cCount++
    //else if .h extension > cHeadCount++

    else if( stat( argv[i], &directory ) == 0 ){
        if( directory.st_mode & S_IFDIR ){
          dirCount++;
        }
     }

    }

   //print values, exit
 }
}
```

Comment: show what you have so far

Comment: What is unclear to you in `man 2 stat`?

Comment: Have you read `man 2 stat`?

Comment: Review https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: @JackVanier I have added what i have

Comment: @RobBor Your use of stat() looks fine. You have a few mismatched `if/else` and missing braces in the code - but please, you should rather tell us what issue you are facing - however, if you have a program that compiles, post that code, the code you did post have a lot of other errors so it does not compile. If the issue is that your code does not compile, you should ask about that instead of asking about stat() though.

Comment: @nos sorry about the mismatch braces. They are not the issue. That just happened bc i was quickly trying to type it up. I still have not been able to figure out why its not counting as a `directory`.

Answer (score 0):

Pay close attention to the documentation: [stat(2)](https://linux.die.net/man/2/stat)

I am also unsure why you are opening the file. You don’t appear to need to do that.

```
#include <stdio.h>

// Please include ALL the files indicated in the manual
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
  int dirCount = 0;

  for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
  {
    struct stat st;
    if (stat( argv[i], &st ) != 0) 
      // If something went wrong, you probably don't care,
      // since you are just looking for directories.
      // (This assumption may not be true. 
      //  Please read through the errors that can be produced on the man page.)
      continue;

    if (S_ISDIR( st.st_mode )) 
      dirCount += 1;
  }

  printf( "Number of directories listed as argument = %d.\n", dirCount );

  return 0;
}
```